# I want to print the highlighted text inside span

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

How can i print the text inside the span tag?
Here is my code. Kinda Naive

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4JIe.png

```
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def fun(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page<=max_pages:
        url = 'https://soundcloud.com/suyash-chavan-4'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text , 'html.parser')
        link  = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'soundTitle__titleContainer'})
        for x in link:
            inner = x.find_all('div', {'class':'soundTitle__usernameTitleContainer'})
            for a in inner:
                before_span = a.find_all('a',{'class':'soundTitle__title sc-link-dark'})
                for span in before_span:
                    href  = span.get('span')
                    print(href.string)

fun(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `href.string` use `href.text`